# access the user's activated virtual environment from within setup.py when they pip install your package from PyPI

Tags: python, c, distutils, setup.py, pypi

My package Foo builds an extension libFoo.so that depends on another package Bar's extension libBar.so, and I don't know a priori where the dependency libBar.so is already installed.  I need to know the dependency's directory in order to set libFoo.so's rpath so that it can find libBar.so at runtime.

I thought a good way to do this might be to import the dependency package Bar in my setup.py and inspect the module to get the directory, since I know where libBar.so will be relative to the Bar package's directory.  That way if they installed from a virtual environment, I would locate the appropriate path.

However, when I try to do this, i.e., when I activate a virtual environment and install my package from PyPI, I find that `import Bar` in the setup.py ends up importing a version from a DIFFERENT virtual environment (I can tell by inspecting the built libFoo.so's rpath after installation).

On the other hand, if I install the Foo package locally by navigating to the source directory and doing `pip install -e .` with my virtual environment activated, the rpath is set correctly...

How can I get the right behavior when installing from PyPI?  In case it helps, here is the relevant code from setup.py:

```
import Bar
barDir = os.path.dirname(inspect.getfile(Bar))
```

When I activate my environment and install from PyPI, barDir is

`/Users/me/anaconda/envs/WRONGENVIRONMENT/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bar`

When I activate my environment and install locally, barDir is

`/Users/me/anaconda/envs/RIGHTENVIRONMENT/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bar`

I'm running OS X 10.10.5 and using conda environments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a stupid caching problem (pip install was not getting the latest package from PyPI, but using a cached copy of an older version I had been testing with).  I had to do

```
pip install --no-cache-dir Foo
```

to ensure I was getting a fresh version

Answer (score 1):

Try using `pkg_resources` from `setuptools`: https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/pkg_resources.html.

Something like:

```
from pkg_resources import resource_string
libbar = resource_string('Bar', 'libBar.so')
```

Comment: libBar.so is one level above bar/__init__.py so this doesn't find it.  Is there a setuptools / pkg_resources way to simply get the directory where a given module's __init__.py resides?  I can't seem to find one...

Comment: I'm not sure, but there's a way to get any resource if it was part of installation package via `setuptools` functions, and that's one of possible ways I wrote above. Please, see the link I provided to find another function, that will suit your situation better. Also you can try to get `__init__.py` as above and then using `glob` and `/../libBar.so` get the file.